# One Java Generics function to merge 3 types of loops

Tags: java, generics

**I wonder if there is ONE generic JAVA function to MERGE these essentially similar 4 for loop into??**

Optional Arguement:

```
public static <E> void loopA(E... list) {
    String str="";
    for (E val : list) {
      str+= val.toString();            
    }        
}
```

Array type E:

```
public static <E> void loopB(E[] list) {
    String str="";
    for (E val : list) {
      str+= val.toString();            
    }        
}
```

Set collection type E:

```
public static <E> void loopC(Set<E> list) {
    String str="";
    for (E val : list) {
      str+= val.toString();            
    }        
}
```

List collection type E:

```
public static <E> void loopD(List<E> list) {
    String str="";
    for (E val : list) {
      str+= val.toString();            
    }        
}
```

the ABOVE 4 into ONE of this:

```
public static <E> void loopSigma(...){
    String str="";
    for (E val : list) {
      str+= val.toString();            
    }        
}
```

Comment: To make the java syntax MORE COMPACT and DENSE.

Comment: I have a quick question, are you using **Java 8**, or older?

Comment: The best you can do is `public static <E> void loopX(Iterable<E> ite)`, but for arrays you'll need to keep one separate method (the varargs one) and call `loopX` by wrapping the array with `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: I read the various intelligent answers given belows, :D.
I was trying to show 2 points. Java syntax is still currently not too compact and require too many temporary objects created in the heap rather than in the stacks, SINCE the JVM is a register-stack bytecoode machines.

Comment: If you want to concatenate multiple `String`s, don't use `+=`, use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: The point is not StringBuilder or +=. I was trying to make the code more readable online.

Comment: @MatthewOng whether compact and dense code is more readable would be debatable on a case-by-case basis. I'd personally prefer a bit more verbose code which is easier to understand and debug. Besides that, you seem to try and show "flaws" of Java rather than to solve a specific problem (as indicated by your comments) and that doesn't seem to fit the purpose of SO too well.

Comment: @Thomas: Yes. This is a case by case issue. However, a more dense code also meant lower line of code for Unit Testing and higher percentage for line of coverage. Even when the MCDC Coverage is not take into this consideration.

Comment: Well, reducing lines of code would not necessarily reduce the amount of unit testing needed, it's basically the complexity of the code itself that influences the tests. And, IMO, code coverage should always taken with a grain of salt since often low coverage is not a sign of low quality or missing tests.

Comment: If the above 4 functions were somehow compile into one function(since the semantic is the almost the same), does not that meant there is now only 4 lines of statement to be tested instead of the current 16?

Comment: I like to start discussion on another thread about this DENSELY READBLE CODE: Welcome constructive discussion for JAVA developer shown here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525943/any-suggestions-densely-readable-java-code

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you use Java 8, you can do it the functional way like this:

```
public static <E> String loop(Collection<E> collection) {
    return collection.stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .reduce((a, b) -> a + b)
        .get();
}
```

Sadly, the array/vararg is not a `Collection`, but vararg is an array, so you should have a single another method for those:

```
public static <E> String loop(E... elements) {
    return loop(Arrays.asList(elements));
}
```

Comment: Sergey. :D I am glad you undertood my question precisely.

Comment: I read the various intelligent answers given belows, :D. I was trying to show 2 points. Java syntax is still currently not too compact and require too many temporary objects created in the heap rather than in the stacks, SINCE the JVM is a register-stack bytecoode machines.

Comment: You don't actually give any better answer than others did, and there is also a lack of explanation of mechanisms behind that.

Comment: @MatthewOng you realize that there's a temporary object involved here as well?

Comment: HI EVERYONE:
Sadly, the array/vararg is not a Collection, but vararg is an array, so you should have a single another method for those: <<< That was what I was looking for. TO be used for my other thread which will be posted later(after 90mins).

Comment: Use `Collectors.joining()` instead of `reduce()`. I thought about `reduce()` at first with `reduce("", (x,y) -> x+y)` but that would create many objects on the heap, and I'm not even sure if it runs sequentially.

Comment: I like to start discussion on another thread about this DENSELY READBLE CODE: Welcome constructive discussion for JAVA developer shown here: stackoverflow.com/questions/30525943/… –  Matthew Ong

Comment: You mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525943/any-suggestions-densely-readable-java-code

Answer (score 2):

I would keep the method with the varargs parameter and would introduce a method with a `Collection<E>` parameter (which will be called from the *varargs* method).

For example:

```
public static <E> void loopA(E... list) {
    loopSigma(Arrays.asList(list)); 
}

public static <E> void loopSigma(Collection<E> collection){
    String str="";
    for (E val : collection) {
      str += val.toString();
    }        
}
```

Additionally, if you're on Java8, you can re-factor the `loopSigma()` method body to one line:

```
String str = collection.stream().collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: No need to specify a parameter to joining if you plan to concatenate the Strings with no space. Also you need to map to each Object to its String representation before.

Comment: @AlexisC.
The point is not the string joining. Its about the Compacting of syntax with fewest heap object created in syntax.

Comment: @MatthewOng, but he's comment is accurate and correct. It's good that there's someone who can point out something to be improved. :)

Comment: `loopSigma` could be improved a bit more by using the `StringBuilder` class instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @Lii, string concatenation uses `StringBuilder` behind the scenes. It's just more readable. :)

Comment: @kocko: Although I suspect this is implementation dependent, I think that in the common case you get one `StringBuilder` _for each string concatenation expression_. In this case that means that you get a new `StringBuilder` instance and a new `String` instance for each iteration of the loop, making the whole thing a _O(n^2)_ operation. Since the collection could contain a lot of elements that could become a problem. This is how an Eclipse compiled class behaves during debugging in any case.

Answer (score 1):

A and B are basically equivalent with B being more flexible in terms of calling. C and D can be replaced by a method with a `Collection<E>` parameter.

To "merge" the logic into one method call that method from the other (overloading):

```
public static <E> void loop(Collection<E> coll) {
   String str=""; //better use a StringBuilder here
   for (E val : coll) {
     str+= val.toString();            
   }        
}   

public static <E> void loop(E... list) {
  loop( Arrays.asList(list) );
}
```

Comment: Yes. Good try. But there is an extra Temporary Heap Object created Array.asList(list).

Comment: @MatthewOng yes but that object is really small (just a wrapper around the array) and you also didn't state that as a requirement. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Java 8`, then you could create a `Stream<E>` from both collections and arrays, then write the `loopSigma` method which is essentially a `joining` collector.

```
public static <E> Stream<E> toStream(E... list) {
    return Arrays.stream(list);
}

public static <E> Stream<E> toStream(Collection<E> list) {
    return list.stream();
}

public String loopSigma(Stream<E> stream) {
    return stream.map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Then you could

```
Set<E> thingy = ...;
String string = loopSigma(YourStreamUtils.toStream(thingy));
```

I haven't tested it yet though but I think it should work.

Comment: Yes. I am on JDK 1.8. Good try.

Comment: But I would get rid of these `toStream` methods.  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use polymorphizm, and you can make two methods in one utility class:

```
public static <E> void loopSigma(E... list){
    String str="";
    for (E val : list) {
      str+= val.toString();            
    }        
}

public static <E> void loopSigma(Collection<E> list){
    String str="";
    for (E val : list) {
      str+= val.toString();            
    }        
}
```

There is no way to treat Collections and Arrays the same from the method signature.

But if you would have those two methods in some utility. You can call this function, and the proper one will be choosed based on the type you provide. So it will be transparent to you which one is used, from the perspective of usage.

Comment: Close enough but that shows the syntax is not compact enough...:D

Comment: Sorry, this Stackoverflow does not allow 2 correct answer?? :(

Comment: I like to start discussion on another thread about this DENSELY READBLE CODE: Welcome constructive discussion for JAVA developer shown here: stackoverflow.com/questions/30525943/… –  Matthew Ong